# PHP how encode/decode text with key?

Tags: php, decode, encode

Code:

```
$result = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, 'test', $string, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
```

It code encode `$string`. But how decode `$result`?

Tell me please how decode `$result` ?

Comment: This function is deprecated anyway and should not be used anymore. You probably want to use [`mcrypt_generic()`](http://php.net/mcrypt_generic/) instead.

Comment: How did you find out about this encryption method? Use the same approach to find the decryption method too if it exists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Decrypt:

```
//Encryption
$result = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, 'test', $string, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
//Decryption
$decrypt_result = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, 'test', $result, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
```

You need to change mode in arguments and pass encrypted values.

**NOTE: mcrypt_generic() has also been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0.**

Read manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-ecb.php.

Better to use [mcrypt_generic()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php).

```
$cc = 'my secret text';
$key = 'my secret key';
$iv = '12345678';

$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,'','cbc','');

mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$cc);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cipher,$encrypted);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

echo "encrypted : ".$encrypted;
echo "<br>";
echo "decrypted : ".$decrypted;
```

Comment: can you write answer with actually method encode/decode please?

Comment: yes i see - it good answer - but i see `This function has been DEPRECATED` and can you write answer with featured function for encode/decode ?

Comment: NOTE: mcrypt_generic() has also been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0.

Answer (score 14):

See https://gist.github.com/joashp/a1ae9cb30fa533f4ad94

Simple PHP encrypt and decrypt using OpenSSL from Joashp who will work for food

```
/**
 * simple method to encrypt or decrypt a plain text string
 * initialization vector(IV) has to be the same when encrypting and decrypting
 * 
 * @param string $action: can be 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'
 * @param string $string: string to encrypt or decrypt
 *
 * @return string
 */
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';
    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    return $output;
}
$plain_txt = "This is my plain text";
echo "Plain Text =" .$plain_txt. "\n";
$encrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $plain_txt);
echo "Encrypted Text = " .$encrypted_txt. "\n";
$decrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted_txt);
echo "Decrypted Text =" .$decrypted_txt. "\n";
if ( $plain_txt === $decrypted_txt ) echo "SUCCESS";
else echo "FAILED";
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Excellent simple solution I used to encrypt email in formular hidden field, then decrypted when sent !

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.**

Try using MCRYPT_DECRYPT

```
$result = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, 'test', $string, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);

$decrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, 'test', $result, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
echo rtrim($decrypted_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mcrypt_encrypt in ecb mode isntead. mcrypr_ecb is depricated.

to decrypt it you can use: mcrypt_decrypt

Comment: can you write answer with encode/decode on mcrypt_encrypt/mcrypt_decrypt please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Libsodium instead. You can check [Zend](https://www.zend.com/blog/libsodium-and-php-encrypt) for further explanation.

Example:

```
$msg = 'This is a super secret message!';

// Generating an encryption key and a nonce
$key   = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES); // 256 bit
$nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES); // 24 bytes

// Encrypt
$ciphertext = sodium_crypto_secretbox($msg, $nonce, $key);
// Decrypt
$plaintext = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($ciphertext, $nonce, $key);

echo $plaintext === $msg ? 'Success' : 'Error'
```